# WordPress pretty permalinks don't work with Laravel in Nginx config

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nginx

I've my Laravel app running on root domain (domain.com/) and a WordPress site on (domain.com/wordpress/).

Root folder for Laravel app = /var/www/laravel-application/
Root folder for WordPress = /var/www/wp/

Everything works fine with both Laravel and WordPress until I switch on the pretty permalinks in WordPress. I get the Laravel error page 'NotFoundHttpException'. It seems Laravel is intervening with WordPress rewrites.

This is my Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 

    if ($scheme != "https") {
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    root /var/www/laravel-application/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location /wordpress {
            alias /var/www/wp;

    location /wordpress {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
       }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
       }
    }

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

   location ~ /.well-known {
           allow all;
   }
}
```

I've tried practically all suggestions from other topics, none worked. There are no plugins/themes, just basic WordPress install. So far I was able to get WordPress working in the alias folder with plain urls.

I can't figure out why within the alias folder the Laravel routing is still picking up the request on url rewrites.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to add this code in config

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

I have add this to my nginx and it working

Comment: I tried it again in that location block, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself by the config from [this coding magician](http://www.jeffmould.com/2016/02/21/exclude-subdirectory-laravel5-routing/).